# TomCat new Cert not taking affect

Tags: tomcat, certificate

We have a website running on Tomcat whose certificate will epire in a few weeks.  I generated a CSR, got a new cert.  Added that cert to the new store and changed the server.xml file to point to the new store.

HOwever when I go to the page it is still reflecting the existing cert.  I deleted cache, restarted Tomcat, renamed the current store.  How can it use it?  Also did:  keytool -list -keystore D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore -storepass 123456 to verify that the key was in there and it is as a private key.

Comment: Did you restart the server after renewing?

Comment: Yup, restarted Tomcat first, then restarted the server.